# java nio client side use multiplexing

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming, nio

My application instance has both client and server.
and now,there are 4 instances running.
Currently in each instance server uses nio multiplexing to accept and broadcast data.
When client writes to channel and if server reply with some data.Client wait for output from server.
Is it possible to use nio at client side ?
If yes can anybody give me some pointers regarding same ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use NIO on client side. I recommend using JBoss Netty for NIO processing, you may see [client example](http://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.2/guide/html/start.html#d0e656) in it's docs.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible of course to use NIO on the client side but there is rarely much point unless your client deals with hundreds of connections, which is pretty rare. It might have a point in a Web crawler for example.